# Période de transition et période transitoire : différences ?

Tags: synonymes

```
C'est une période de transition.

C'est une période transitoire.
```

Quelle est la différence entre ces deux tournures ?

Comment: Il n'a pas de différence. Souvent, lorsqu'il y a trop de d'article partitif ou préposition dans une phrase, on va opter pour la solution avec l'adjectif.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[Transitoire](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/transitoire)* a deux sens légèrement différents.

Le premier indique un caractère éphémère alors que le deuxième indique un passage graduel d'un état à un autre, c'est à dire une transition (ex. : A → B).

*Période de transition* peut donc toujours être remplacé par *période transitoire* mais, en théorie au moins, il doit pouvoir exister des *périodes transitoires* qui ne sont pas des *périodes de transition* mais des périodes durant lesquelles quelque chose prend brièvement un état instable différent de son état stable habituel (ex. : A → ~ → A).

Comment: @baied'euzellecité La proportion s'inverse avec Google books (deux fois plus de *période de transition* que de *période transitoire*). Si on cherche avec *régime*, c'est l'inverse (6 à 8 fois plus de *régime transitoire*)

Answer (score -1):

### Periode de transition > de passage d'un régime politique à un autre
Période transitoire > Passage                          éphémère de durée limitée